# Кеширование nginx для часто обновляемого сайта?

Tags: nginx, кэширование, ispmanager

Имеется сайт, который парсит разные события и новости с разных сайтов и публикует на сайте (добавление новых записей). Новые записи добавляются довольно часто: каждые 10 минут. Т.е. главная страница меняется каждые 10 минут.

Подскажите, имеет ли смысл включать кеширование в ISPmanager в разделе www-домен (если я правильно понимаю, это Nginx кеширование)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если да, то какой лучше всего период кеширования выбрать, чтобы пользователи при заходе на сайт видели акутальные данные?

И от чего будет будет больше пользы в плане снижения нагрузки: от включения кеширования с периодом жизни 5-8 минут или лучше не включать кеширование вовсе?

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас именно сайт-агрегатор, на котором не публикуются собственные уникальные материалы, то, несмотря на столь частые обновления, основные поисковые сервисы не будут считать ваш сайт `уникально-обновляемым`, следовательно кэширование имеет смысл.

Что касается настроек, то без статистики посещаемости что-то разумное предложить навскидку сложно. Но пару вариантов можно:

1. **В зависимости от нагрузки на сервер.** Если она минимальна, то и включать кэширование пока не имеет смысла. Если, наоборот, велика, то выставить период в несколько часов, оценить влияние, изменить в ту или иную сторону
2. **От частоты посещений пауками поисковых систем.** Проанализировать частоту обращений пауков к разным страницам, выставить время кэширование, примерно равное промежутку между обращениями к самым изменямым страницам.